# Regular Expression matching words using an OR operator

Tags: regex

I have been investigating RegEx's this afternoon, and yes I need a book, however I have finally got my expression doing what I want however one small issue remains that is annoying me!

My expression is basically passed to the blueimp file uploader plugin to allow a range of valid file types to be uploaded based upon their file extension.  So to keep this simple here is what I have come up with which works: -

```
/\bdocx\b|\bxlsx\b|/i
```

So my question is why do I need the final | for this to work, if I remove the final | my expression no longer functions as intended, that is matches with files with an extension of docx or xlsx??

Regards,
Andy

p.s.
Any pointers on good resources on this subject would be awesome so I can do some reading up!

Comment: A good resource that I use for debugging regex is http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it has a nice interface and a good explanation of what you are changing

Comment: In your case, it will be interesting to edit your post to add your code.

Comment: That regular expression matches everything, because the final pipe makes it match the empty string, which can be found in every string.

Comment: But his question is why won't it work without the final pipe? I suspect the answer lies elsewhere in code because the regex looks fine if you remove the unwanted pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex:

```
/\bdocx\b|\bxlsx\b|/i
```

matches 3 strings (ignore case):

1. `docx`
2. `xlsx`
3. `<an empty text>`

Most likely you are getting file names with NO extensions also.

**Good reference on regex: http://regular-expressions.info**